# How to alter autoload php page to connect to web server?

Tags: php, web, drupal, hosting, autoload

I am currently having an issue, when trying to upload my drupal site to biz.nf hosting for the first time. My domain is up and running but even though all the files are on the FTP and have been sent to the domain they are not showing pages.

The domain in question is www.turbojetwashcleaning.co.nf

Thank you

I have tried looking in the autoload.php file but I am unsure of what I need to edit if anything. I was running a local copy of Xampp to make the site run at home which looks great. But as soon as I have used coffee cup FTP to upload the site, I cannot seem to get it to load.

Warning:require(/srv/disk7/2986124/www/turbojetwashcleaning.co.nf/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/disk7/2986124/www/turbojetwashcleaning.co.nf/autoload.php on line 14

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/srv/disk7/2986124/www/turbojetwashcleaning.co.nf/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-7.1.28/share/pear') in /srv/disk7/2986124/www/turbojetwashcleaning.co.nf/autoload.php on line 14

I am hoping that I just need to alter the autoload.php file for my drupal 8 site to automatically load up on the domain provided.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you do have autoload.php file in site root, right? But do you have autoload.php inside your vendor dir? Or even better question - do you have all bundles installed in your vendor dir? If not try running:

`composer install`

from console, from your site root folder (assuming that composer is installed on your remote server).

BTW you question from the title makes no sense. You should never alter drupal's core files by hand.